# Declare non-optional variable without initializing it in constructor

Tags: typescript

I want `A.complexObj` to be a required field, but cannot initialize it in constructor or in-line where it is declared.

```js
class A {
    complexObj: ClassB;

    constructor() {
    }

    onClickOfSomething() {
        this.complexObj = someService.getObj();
    }
}
```

Error: `Property 'complexObj' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Initialise the field directly: `complexObj: ClassB = someService.getObj()`. It's either that or initialising in the constructor, anything else means that `complexObj` is *not* initialised after construction.

Comment: Issue is that `complexObj` can only be initialized in `onClickOfSomething()`

Comment: In that case, you cannot actually have this object with a mandatory `complexObj` property until later. Thus, it's impossible to have the property mandatory and having it unfilled. Either instantiate the object when you can or make it optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, if you aren't assigning `complexObj` in the constructor but you are creating an `A` instance without doing so, then `complexObj` **isn't** a required property.

You have at least two options:

1. Make it not required. If there's an operation `A` provides that it cannot do without `complexObj`, check for `undefined` and throw an error.
2. Use a static builder function that doesn't create the `A` instance until it has a `complexObj` to put in it. That way, you never create an `A` instance without the property being filled in.